# Geth local and remote port numbers

Tags: go-ethereum, peers

I've started three Ethereum nodes using Geth, and they happen to be on the same node. I've specified the ports (30401, 30402, 30403) and used the `--nodiscover` options.

On each of the nodes, I've added the peers using the enodes (using `static-nodes.json`) using the external IPs:

```
enode1@18.222.108.246:30401
enode2@18.222.108.246:30402
enode2@18.222.108.246:30403
```

However, when I attach into the console and observe the peers, I notice that the port number has changed in the enode specification. Also, the local addresses are correct, the remote address have port numbers changed.

```
enode://enode2@18.222.108.246:30402
    network: {
      inbound: true,
      localAddress: "192.168.144.4:52594",
      remoteAddress: "18.222.108.246:30402",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },

enode://enode1@18.222.106.246:46636
    network: {
      inbound: true,
      localAddress: "192.168.144.4:30401",
      remoteAddress: "18.222.108.246:46636",
      static: false,
      trusted: false
    },
```

Does anyone know why the remote port numbers are different? Are the local and remote addresses two ends of a TCP connection?

Comment: It is the nature how IP (internet protocol) works. When you connect to a remote server an unused random local port is assigned to the connection, so the remote server will send their replies to the local port.